# How to reconnect to slime/swank-clojure session?

Tags: emacs, clojure, swank

It seems that whenever I disconnect from clojure slime session, I cannot reconnect again. I am using leiningen to start the swank session (with lein-swank plugin). So, every time I quit emacs (I know I shouldn't) or reboot/logout I have to restart both slime and swank. Is there a way to re-connect to a slime/clojure-swank session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but you have to tell swank not to close the connection:

```
lein swank 4005 "localhost" :dont-close true
```

Note that you have to supply the port and host name if you want to pass the `:dont-close true` portion; `4005` and `"localhost"` are the default values.

In fact, this makes it possible to connect multiple REPLs to the same `swank` instance at the same time! Then you can type in `(def foo :foo)` in one Emacs and see `foo` evaluate to `:foo` in the other. :-)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I get  Wrong number of args passed to: swank$swank

Comment: Apparently this functionality was introduced in a commit to Leiningen (lein-swank resides in the main Leiningen repo) from 9 Feb *without* the `host` argument, then `host` was added on 21 Mar. Hopefully you're using the version which doesn't accept `host` -- try dropping it from the command line. If you're using a pre-9 Feb Leiningen, perhaps this might be a reason to upgrade!

Comment: I am using whatever lein installed as a dependency (not sure, but it claims to be 1.1.0). When I remove "localhost" from the command I get the same error.

Comment: The solution seems to be to replace 1.1.0 lein-swank with 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT in the dev-dependencies. Then it takes all the mentioned arguments.

Comment: Be sure not to use the `sayoonara` command within SLIME, as that asks the Swank server running in the Lisp host to shut down. Instead, use the `disconnect` command. As of today, that causes some error messages to be printed by the Swank server, but it does seem to accommodate subsequent reconnection to the same running Clojure process.